# append a globally defined list from inside of a function in R

Tags: r, list, pmap

I am using the walk function to iterate over my list of lists and append a list element to every sub-list.

```
.insideFunction <- function(sublistName, arg2){

newListElement <- "Hello"
newListElement <- as.list(newListElement)
names(newListElement) <- "newListElement"

myList[[sublistName]] <- append(myList[[sublistName]], newListElement)

}


walk(names(myList), .insideFunction, someTable)
```

The problem is that the list `myList`, which is defined globally doesn't change.
I am currently using the global assignment operator inside of the `.insideFunction` to force R to overwrite the sublist.

```
myList[[sublistName]] <<- append(myList[[sublistName]], newListElement)
```

How can I avoid using the global assignment operator, but still append the globally defined list from inside a function?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `walk` to create a modified version of a list by applying a function to every element e.g. add 2 to each sub list:

```r
library(purrr)

data <- list(
  list("foo", 1),
  list("bar", 1)
)
data
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "foo"
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "bar"
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 1

newListElement <- "Hello"
newListElement <- as.list(newListElement)
names(newListElement) <- "newListElement"

data %>% map(~ .x %>% c(newListElement))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "foo"
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[1]]$newListElement
#> [1] "Hello"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "bar"
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]$newListElement
#> [1] "Hello"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: is there maybe a problem with the append function? I change it to map and still nothing happens

Comment: `.insideFunction` must be defined before `map` and not inside. See my revised answer.

Comment: yes, sorry my bad. I edited the question as well. So I firstly defined the .insideFunction, which I then use in the map. The function does more than just appending. The append is the last step in the function. But still no change in the global object myList

Comment: it seems that you are not using any inside function in your map?

Comment: The formula `~ .x %>% c(newListElement)` is to define the function I want to apply to each element. It will be converted internally e.g. to `data %>% map(function(x) {c(x, newListElement)})`. This function is anonymous without any explicit name e.g. `.insideFunction`. You do not need names if the function is not being called elsewhere.

Comment: The first argument of map is the list and not the names. The second is the function or formula: `map(seq(5), function(x){ x + 1 })`